# Return table data with Delphi ISAPI

Tags: delphi, isapi, delphi-xe6

I first created a regular datasnap application with server and client. In order to get data from server I have sqlconnection connected to DSProviderConnection and that is connected to ClinetDataSet. Then all I have to do is set ClientDataset commandText and open it.

But with ISAPI I am not sure how to achive the client side connections. For now I have DSRestConnection on CliendModuleUnit. Can I still have SQLConnection and DSProviderConnection on it too. If Yes then I am not sure how to set properties for SQLConnection with ISAPI.

I basically want to pass database table data from server to client in an ISAPI datasnap applicaiton. And just display the data in grid. Please let me know if there is other better ways to do this.

I am using XE6.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the host/url where your datasnap server listens for incoming connections. Where is it, depends on how you configured the web server:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Connecting_the_Client_to_DataSnap_Server

Comment: Thanks LDS for reply. Sorry I am very new to datasnap and ISAPI. Can you give a bit more detail. I saw the link you provided, still I am not sure how to get ISAPI part done. Can you please give some kind of tutorial like steps. Thanks.

Comment: If you look into the docs, you will find the examples you need... for example this one: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Tutorial:_DataSnap_Application_Using_an_ISAPI_DLL_Server :)
I would suggest you to give a look to the tutorials available. Once this information where in the "Development Guide" which came with Delphi, now are in the doc wiki.

Comment: Thanks again LDS. I did looked at that and I am able to run this tutorial without any issue. But now I am not sure how do I put database capability in this. Can you tell me what additional steps I need to take for it to have Database functionality. Thanks.

Comment: Database functionalities are automatically available when you use any TDataset descendant in the server module, provider components lined to them, and TClientDataset in the client linked to the provider through the proper connection component.
Again, if you looked through the documentation you would have found:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Creating_multi-tiered_applications_Index which explains you everything :)
Take some time to read it, it's time well spent - SO may be quicker but will also tell you less...